# How do I interpret and report the output of a logistic regression in R on data that are all binary (0,1)?

Tags: logistic, interpretation, odds-ratio

My minimum adequate model is shown below. My independent variables (e.g. One, Five) represent habitat categories for which species have either been designated to (i.e. the assessment found that they occur there) or not (they are considered not to occur there). My dependent variable groups species as climate change threatened or not. So all variables, independent and dependent, are binary (0,1).

**My hypothesis question is as follows:**

'Do species for which climate change is a known threat show similarities in terms of habitat associations and is one or more predominant habitat evident compared with species that are not threatened by climate change?'

**Specific questions I would like to be answered include:**

1. Would calculating an odds ratio be of use to me (considering all my data are binary)?
2. What sort of statements do the output I have (below)/or recommended additional statistics (e.g. odds ratios) allow me to make?

Thanks!

**Output:**

```
Deviance Residuals:  Min      1Q    Median   3Q     Max 
                   -0.6900 -0.3589 -0.2550 -0.1931 2.8634

Coefficients:  Estimate Std.Error  z value  Pr(>|z|) 
(Intercept)    -2.18672  0.09957  -21.961   < 2e-16 *** 
One            -1.23943  0.13614   -9.104   < 2e-16 *** 
Five            0.75144  0.17228    4.362  1.29e-05 *** 
Seven          -0.66517  0.34117   -1.950   0.05122 . 
Fourteen       -0.55602  0.17454   -3.186   0.00144 **

Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1).
```

Comment: Are the habitat categories mutually exclusive?

Answer (score 2):

You would interpret the regression results as you would any logistic regression model with dummy variables.  That is, odds ratios are interpreted as the odds of the category in question relative to the reference category.  That said, your model effectively only has one explanatory variable--habitat--so what you show us here is just the binary association between your outcome (threatened/not threatened) and habitat type, i.e. crude ORs. Given that it is likely that other factors affect the species' "threatened status," you need to control for those other factors in your model. Otherwise, the crude ORs are a biased estimate of the effect of habitat type on threatened status.

I do not see a problem with having a model with all binary predictors if the data call for it, though you may run into problems if you have small cell sizes. Some variables are necessarily categorical, e.g. habitat type. Sometimes you may need to categorize continuous variables if the relationship between the continuous variable and the outcome is not linear.

When you fit a model limited dependent variables, such as logit, multinomial logit, ordered logit, probit, tobit, Poisson, etc., the coefficients are not directly interpretable.  Therefore, you will need to calculate some transformation of the $\beta$, either odds ratios (as you have done here), marginal effects, predictive margins, etc.

Note also that you can draw conclusions about different habitat types associated with higher or lower likelihood of having threatened status relative to the omitted category, but if you want to know whether habitat type overall is associated  with threatened status, you will need to do an F-test of the joint significance of your dummy variables.  In a model with just one explanatory variable (as you have here), the model F-test is equivalent to the F-test I just described in the previous sentence.

Finally, you should enter all categories of habitat but one into your model. The omitted category is your reference category, and serves as the group that other habitat categories are compared to with regard to risk of threatened status. If you enter only some categories and not others, the omitted categories will all be lumped together in the reference category.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I'm not sure I need to control for other factors that may contribute to a "CC threatened" status, however, as I am merely trying to determine which habitats are important for CC threatened species and which for non-CC threatened species. I am unclear whether or not you recommend calculating and reporting odds ratios instead of beta coefficients, and why? Thanks

Comment: Just seen your first question. In answer, yes the habitats are mutually exclusive.

Comment: If there are other factors besides habitat that affect CC status that are related to habitat, failing to control for those factors would make you overstate or understate the association between habitat and CC status.  We call this Omitted Variable Bias.  Sometimes the significance of a binary association goes away after you control for other factors.  What you are doing is fine for exploratory analysis (deciding what to include in a full model), but if you were to write a scientific paper for publication, the binary association may not be enough.

Comment: I have added a couple of sentences about interpreting parameter estimates of limited dependent variable models and dummy variables.

Comment: I feel I haven't described to you well enough the question I wish to answer. My research is based on the IUCN Red List's data for which I have separated species based on whether or not the assessment considers them CC threatened or not. Rather than attempting to comprehensively analyse a range of variables on their importance for determining whether or not species are threatened by CC, I am exploring the importance of different habitats for CC and non-CC threatened species. I will then be discussing the potential reasons for my findings e.g. assessor bias, habitat associations with CC etc.

Comment: I assume then that the F-test would be of no real use in my case. Do you agree? I understand that beta values are difficult to interpret, but can I not just use their sign (+ or -) to indicate whether the habitat association is more important for CC or non-CC threatened species? I ask you this as I am struggling to understand how an odds ratio will be of use as an alternative (and what I can say about the value) given that my predictor variables are all binary (either designated (1) or not (0)).

Comment: Re: your comment about the F-test, I disagree. I think it's important for you to be able to say *overall* whether habitat is significantly associated with CC status, since it is your main research question.  It looks here that your F-test is probably going to be significant.  Second, I assume you fitted a logit model, so that is why I encouraged you to either compute the odds ratios or marginal effects.  Yes, you can use the sign ("more likely" vs. "less likely"), but don't you want to know by how much?  The OR and MEs will tell you both direction and magnitude of the difference.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, binary covariates are interpreted relative to the base/omitted category, so your interpretation would be something like "species in habitat one are X times [X = the odds ratio] less likely than species in [base category] to have threatened status [assuming threatened =1 and not threatened=0]."  More often than not, it is the magnitude that is of interest.  Sure, you can have a positive relationship, but if the OR is only 1.02, is it *really* biologically significant, even if it is statistically significant?

Comment: 1. Point taken about the F-test. Can I calculate it from my R output shown above?                                                                                               2. I used a log-log link function as the dependent variable (CC threatened or not) group sizes were very different in size. I'm not sure if this affects anything though (may be wrong?).                                              3. I'm also unclear what this base category you mentioned is? Are you referring to habitats I removed in the stepwise reduction of my model (the least significant), of which there were many?

Comment: I'm not an R user, so I cannot tell you how to do it in that package.  I imagine the package will spit it out for you (look for it at the top or bottom of the output), otherwise the documentation for the command you used will probably have that information.  In addition, you can search the rest of CV for how to do a post-estimation F-test in R.

Comment: Re:  "3. I'm also unclear what this base category you mentioned is." If you want to know the association between habitat and CC status, you need to include ALL of the habitat categories, except for one. This omitted category is the base or reference category. Because all of your different habitat types are ALL part of the measure "habitat type," you cannot pick and choose which dummy to enter in your model based on their individual significance levels.  They must all be considered at the same time (jointly) to determine whether habitat is significantly associated with CC status.

Comment: I inputted all habitats jointly initially and then reduced the model one habitat (least sig.) at a time with attention to the AIC value using the criterion of a delta AIC of less than 2. Did you think I'd assessed each habitat separately?

Comment: Regardless, you shouldn't remove individual habitat categories if they are supposed to be measures of the same construct (habitat type).  You need to enter ALL habitat categories into the model as dummies, with the exception of one category, which will serve as your base category.  If you have 10 habitat types, you need to enter 9 habitat dummies in the model.  Otherwise, if you entered only 3 based on AIC, your stat package will group the excluded 7 categories together and call it the "base category" used to get the parameter estimates for the 3 you entered in the model.

Comment: Is this a rule for all logistic regression analyses? It's just that I've had no indication from my dissertation supervisor that I must carry out my analysis in this way.

Comment: It's a rule when you are entering your categorical variables as dummy variables.  Dummy variables that measure the same construct must be entered into the model as a set.  See the section on polytomous factors beginning on page 124 of this document to see how to properly use dummy variables in regression models http://www.sagepub.com/upm-data/21120_Chapter_7.pdf.  Many regression models are based on linear regression with the "link function" changed depending on the constraints on the outcome, so the rules for dummy vbls in OLS apply to logistic, probit, tobit, Cox, Poisson, etc.

Comment: A useful citation for Odds Ratios for ecologist is Rita and Komonnen "Odds Ratio: An Ecologically Sound Tool to Compare Proportions" http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.5735/086.045.0106

Comment: Thanks for the links! Is this the case regardless of the fact that my predictors are mutually exclusive (e.g. desert, forest)?

Comment: This is the case because your predictors are mutually exclusive.  Please read the PDF from Sage I referred you to.  Think of it this way: if you have 3 yes/no habitat types and you enter all 3 habitat dummies, your stat package will automatically omit one because entering all 3 will result in perfect multicollinearity w.r.t. the "habitat type" variable (you can try this yourself, enter all of your habitat dummies in the model and see what happens). Conversely, if you enter just "forest," then "desert" and the 3rd category will be lumped together b/c they both have a value of 0 for "forest"

Comment: Same logic why for sex, we only use one indicator to denote male or female.  You do not enter dummies for both "Male" (0/1) and "Female" (0/1) into the same model because of multicollinearity...you can, but your stat package will kick one of those out if you do. If you have 3 sex categories (male, female, intersex), you will need to enter 2 of those categories into the model (maybe male and female).  The ORs and MEs for males will be relative to intersex (the omitted category), and the same goes for females.  Again, $\beta$'s of logit models are not directly interpretable, save for direction

Comment: My data include many cases whereby species are designated to more than one habitat. I am studying birds and mammals so range sizes incorporate many varieties of habitat, which my data account for.  Thus it is necessary that I include all categories as habitat exclusion would mean excluding a lot of data for many species from my analysis.

Comment: I did run collinearity diagnostics and, for habitats that were found to have colllinearity with each other (of which there were few, but for example 'marine neritic' and 'marine oceanic'), the least biologically important was excluded from my analysis.

Answer (score 0):

A useful tool for interpreting the results of a logit is the Zelig package, http://zeligproject.org/, by Gary King et al. It has tools similar to the popular clarify package they made for stata.